# What is the different between ls > list and ls >> list?

Tags: linux

I was wondering what the difference is between ls > list and ls >> list is and what the purpose of these commands is?

Comment: Which commands? `ls`? Or the two redirection operators `>` and `>>`? Does [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/159514/22222) answer your question?

Comment: I know what ls does, but what is the purpose of the redirection operators > and >> and what do they do? Thanks

Comment: OK, then that is answered in the duplicate. Please leave me a comment if it isn't.

Answer (score 3):

`>` writes to a file, replacing its contents.  `>>` appends to a file, adding on more contents.  this is set up by the shell with a open file descriptor (handle) passed on to the program (`ls` in your case)